# JBoss adds user to wrong realm found in property files

Tags: java, jboss, realm, jboss6.x

I had JBoss installed a while ago so I eventually forgot the password and username used for managing it (I mean the management console on port 9990).

I tried to reset the password by running the `add-user.sh` script but messed it up and now every user I add is created in the `admin` realm:

```
Enter the details of the new user to add.
Using realm 'admin' as discovered from the existing property files.
```

I do not need this realm, I just need the admin user to manage JBoss  (presumably, this is the Management realm).

I tried to do the following:

1. Removed the admin line from `mgmt-users.properties` and `mgmt-groups.properties` in the `standalone/configuration` and `domain/configuration`
2. Tried to find the 'admin' realm in `standalone.xml` and `standalone-full.xml` but to no avail.

My question is how to create/reset the password of admin in the Management at last?

Also, where can I find the existing property files that JBoss mentions and override it to make it use the Management realm instead?

Answer (score 0):

Had to reinstall JBoss and the problem gone.

Comment: I am not sure this really qualifies as an answer.